# Can I use iis express on XP to test compatibility of web app on IIS7/windows-7?

Tags: iis-7, iis-express

I have a web application, that runs perfectly on IIS 5.1 installed on windows XP (SP2 or better). I wish to test its compatibility on IIS on Windows-7. I read that IIS Express 7.5 is equivallent to IIS7 and runs on XP. Can I use IIS express installed on XP machine to test the application's compatibility on IIS/Windows-7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. IIS Express is not IIS 7 (derived from IIS 7 code base does not mean there is no difference.

Besides, the most important thing is your web application may have indirect dependencies on the OS, which can be quite different from Windows XP to Windows 7.

So if your goal is to test compatibilties, doing that on Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use IIS Express to test your app on XP.
(IIS Express requires XP sp3)

Comment: But shall it prove/test its compatibility on IIS7/Windows-7 combination?

Comment: If your applications works with iis express 7.5, then it will work with IIS 7.5/Windown7. (IIS 7.0 is in Vista and W2k8 and IIS 7.5 is in Win7 and W2k8 R2. IIS Express 7.5 is light wieght version of IIS 7.5 )

Comment: The conclusion "then it will work with IIS 7.5/Windows 7" is too early.